# Combining select distinct with group and ordering

Tags: sql, sqlite

A simplified example for illustration: Consider a table "fruit" with 3 columns: name, count and the date purchased. Need an alphabetical list of the fruits and their count the last time they were bought. I am a bit confused by the order of sorting and how distinct is applied. My attempt -

```
drop table if exists fruit;
create table fruit (
        name    varchar(8),
        count   integer,
        dateP   datetime
);

insert into fruit (name, count, dateP) values
        ('apple',  4, '2014-03-18 16:24:37'),
        ('orange', 2, '2013-12-11 11:20:16'),
        ('apple',  7, '2014-07-05 08:34:21'),
        ('banana', 6, '2014-06-20 19:10:15'),
        ('orange', 6, '2014-07-22 17:41:12'),
        ('banana', 4, '2014-08-15 21:26:37'), -- last
        ('orange', 5, '2014-12-11 11:20:16'), -- last
        ('apple',  3, '2014-09-25 18:54:32'), -- last
        ('apple',  5, '2014-02-05 18:47:18'),
        ('apple', 12, '2013-09-25 14:18:57'),
        ('banana', 5, '2013-04-18 15:59:04'),
        ('apple',  9, '2014-01-29 11:47:45');

-- Expecting:
--     apple     3
--     banana    4
--     orange    5

        select distinct name, count
                from fruit
                group by name
                order by name, dateP;

-- Produces:
--     apple     9
--     banana    5
--     orange    5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
select f1.name,f1.count
from
fruit f1
inner join
(select name,max(dateP) date_P from fruit group by name) f2
on f1.name = f2.name and f1.dateP = f2.date_P
order by f1.name
```

**EDITED** for the last line :)

Comment: Awesome! For the last line, it complained about "ambiguous column name: name" - changed that to f1.name and it worked like a charm. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
SELECT fruit.name, fruit.count, fruit.dateP
FROM fruit
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT name, Max(dateP) AS lastPurchased
        FROM fruit
        GROUP BY name
    ) AS dt ON (dt.name = fruit.name AND dt.lastPurchased = fruit.dateP )
```

Here is a demo of this example on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c5bd0/2/0).

Answer (score 0):

When faced before with a similar situation I resolved as follows, it requires the use of a primary key, in this case I have added `UID`.

```
SELECT a.Name,a.Count FROM Fruit a WHERE a.UID IN 
    (SELECT b.UID FROM Fruit b 
    WHERE b.Name = a.Name ORDER BY b.DateP Desc,b.UID DESC LIMIT 1)
```

This also avoids the possibility that the same fruit was purchased twice at the exact same time; unlikely in this example but in a large scale system it is a possibility which could come back to haunt you. It handles this by ordering by UID as well so it will choose the purchase most recently added to the table (assuming incrementing primary key).

**Edited to remove the `TOP 1` invalid syntax**

Comment: SQLite has no `TOP 1`.

Comment: My bad, never actually used SQLLite, now edited to use `LIMIT'

Answer (score 0):

In SQLite 3.7.11 or later, you can use MAX/MIN to select from which record in a group other values are returned (but this requires that you have that maximum in the result):

```
SELECT name, count, MAX(dateP)
FROM fruit
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY name
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna improve your performance, use Common Table Expressions instead of nested Select clauses.

Comment: This isn't an answer, this should be a comment or should give some example of what you mean by way of an answer to the OPs question.